# How do I get a forloop working with a foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running a query to bring back products from my database on a search page. Here is what I want to do:

- I want to place some text after 6 and 12 of the 18 paginated results on each page.
- If a search is run and less than 12 results come back, I want to show the text after 6 only

How do I work in my for-loop within my foreach?

Here is my code. Where should the code be placed?

for:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++)
    @if (in_array($i,array(6,12,18)) && count($products) >= 12)
      <h2> example code </h2>
    @elseif ($i == 6 && count($products) < 12)
      <h2>example</h2>
    @endif
@endfor
```

foreach:

```
 @foreach ($products as $product)

                <div class="row sing">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"><div class="img"><div class=" container img-s" style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/' . $product->image)}}'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center center;"></div></div></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="info-productsearch">
                    <div class="name-holder">
                    <h4>{{$product->productname}}</h4>
                        @if(Count($product->reviews) >0)
                        <p>Rated : {{number_format($product->reviews->avg('ratings'),2)}}/ 5, from {{$product->reviews->count()}} reviews</p>
                        @else
                            <p>Rated : Yet To Be Reviewed</p>

                        @endif

                    </div>

                    <p class="location-det"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> {{$productt->producttypes}}, {{$sight->productrefcode}}</p>
                    <p>{{substr(strip_tags($product->prodinfo), 0, 325)}}<a class="find-out-more" href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"> (...Find out more)</a></p>
                </div>
                </div>

    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
@foreach ($products as $index => $product)
    <div class="row sing">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"><div class="img"><div class=" container img-s" style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/' . $product->image)}}'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;"></div></div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="info-productsearch">
                <div class="name-holder">
                    <h4>{{$product->productname}}</h4>
                    @if(Count($product->reviews) >0)
                        <p>Rated : {{number_format($product->reviews->avg('ratings'),2)}}/ 5, from {{$product->reviews->count()}} reviews</p>
                    @else
                        <p>Rated : Yet To Be Reviewed</p>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <p class="location-det"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> {{$productt->producttypes}}, {{$sight->productrefcode}}</p>
                <p>{{substr(strip_tags($product->prodinfo), 0, 325)}}<a class="find-out-more" href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"> (...Find out more)</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (in_array($index, array(5,11,17)) && count($products) >= 12)
            <h2> example code </h2>
        @elseif ($index == 5 && count($products) < 12)
            <h2>example</h2>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tried that, I get the else if but not the if. Strange one as the else if shows after 7 products not the 6

Comment: Doesn't work all i get is after the 7th product the example code. which is wrong as it should be after 6 and 12 unless their is less than 12 results it should be after 6. My understanding of this isnt great but what is that In_array and then another Array close after doing as it seems to be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to combine these into one for each loop with an if conditional statement.

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<div class="row sing">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"><div class="img"><div class=" container img-s" style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/' . $product->image)}}'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
                            background-size: cover;
                            background-position: center center;"></div></div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="info-productsearch">
                <div class="name-holder">
                <h4>{{$product->productname}}</h4>
                    @if(Count($product->reviews) >0)
                    <p>Rated : {{number_format($product->reviews->avg('ratings'),2)}}/ 5, from {{$product->reviews->count()}} reviews</p>
                    @else
                        <p>Rated : Yet To Be Reviewed</p>


                    @endif

                </div>

                <p class="location-det"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> {{$productt->producttypes}}, {{$sight->productrefcode}}</p>
                <p>{{substr(strip_tags($product->prodinfo), 0, 325)}}<a class="find-out-more" href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"> (...Find out more)</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
@if (in_array($i,array(6,12,18)) && count($products) >= 12)
  <h2> example code </h2>
@elseif ($i == 6 && count($products) < 12)
  <h2>example</h2>
@endif
```

Edit: I opened this thread and didn't post an answer until later on. Looks like adamyi has posted a very similar answer in that time. His is more correct because he fixed your array index issues, I overlooked those.

Comment: Doesn't work all i get is after the 7th product the example code. which is wrong as it should be after 6 and 12 unless their is less than 12 results it should be after 6. My understanding of this isnt great but what is that In_array and then another Array close after doing as it seems to be ignored?

Comment: Did you use array(6,12,18) or array(5,11,17) as @adamyi suggested? Or did you try both? adamyi's answer should work because the first index is 0, not 1, so I'm interested if you tried (5, 11, 17) and got the same result as (6,12,18)?

Comment: Yes, mine clearly was missing some syntax corrections for sure, I was going for a logic flow and forgot to adjust that stuff. But from a numbers perspective, if his didn't work that is curious. Index == 5 should be the 6th result, so it's odd that it's still returning the 6th index instead.

Comment: Its all a bit strange it does come back with something after 6 but this is where products is more than 12. so it seems that the first if is being ignored.

Comment: That must mean that the first if condition is not being met, so it is going to the elseif condition. That one specifies just to return after the 6th index which means that section of code is working correctly. You need to identify what condition isn't being me in the if statement.